# Sorting objects that are pairs of ints

Tags: java, sorting

I have created in my program my own LinkedList (not from java.util) of cards.

Each card is an object made of ***2 ints*** - the first one is a value of a card (from 1 to 13), second is a colour for a card (from 0 to 3).

The list is randomly generated and the list is created when a value is 0.

Now I want to upgrade my method of adding cards to sort them while adding. ***First by value, then by color***.

Here is how my code looks like for now:

```
public class Lista {
private Element pocz; //start
public int rozmiar;

public Lista() {
    boolean zrobione = false;
    while (zrobione != true) {
        Karta karta = new Karta();
        if (karta.getWartosc() == 0) {
            zrobione = true;
        } else {
            this.dodaj(karta);
        }
    }
}

public void dodaj(Karta k) {
    if (pocz == null) {
        pocz = new Element(k);
    }

    Element pom = new Element(k);
    Element obecny = pocz;
    if (obecny != null) {
        while (obecny.getNext() != null) {
            obecny = obecny.getNext();
        }
        obecny.setNext(pom);
    }
    rozmiar++;
}
```

I have been thinking for a solution for quite a bit and came up with something like:

```
public void dodaj(Karta k){
    if(rozmiar == 0) {
        if (pocz == null) {
            pocz = new Element(k);
        }

        Element pom = new Element(k);
        Element obecny = pocz;
        if (obecny != null) {
            while (obecny.getNext() != null) {
                obecny = obecny.getNext();
            }
            obecny.setNext(pom);
        }
        rozmiar++;
    }
    else{
        Element pom = new Element(k);
        Element obecny = pocz;
        boolean znalezione = false;
        if(obecny != null && !znalezione){
            while(obecny.getNext() != null && !znalezione){
                if(obecny.getKarta().wartosc < obecny.getNext().getKarta().wartosc) {
                    obecny.setNext(pom);
                    znalezione = true;
                }
                else if(obecny.getKarta().wartosc == obecny.getNext().getKarta().wartosc){
                    if(obecny.getKarta().kolor < obecny.getNext().getKarta().kolor){
                        obecny.setNext(pom);
                        znalezione = true;
                    }
                    else if(obecny.getKarta().kolor == obecny.getNext().getKarta().kolor){
                        obecny.setNext(pom);
                        znalezione = true;
                    }
                    else{
                        obecny = obecny.getNext();
                        obecny.setNext(pom);
                        znalezione = true;
                    }
                }
                else{
                    obecny = obecny.getNext();
                    obecny.setNext(pom);
                    znalezione = true;
                }
            }
        }
        rozmiar++;
    }
}
```

But this method makes my list contain only 2 cards and I am not sure if it works at all...
Sorry for not English names of variables and classes.

Example of what I want to achieve:

```
Before sorting
11 2
5 3
2 3
13 0
1 2
5 2
1 1
5 1

After sorting
1 1
1 2
2 3
5 1
5 2
5 3
11 2
13 0
```

`rozmiar` is size of List
`wartosc` is value of a card
`kolor` is colour of a card
`dodaj` means "add"

Answer (score 0):

It's very hard to understand that code without knowing what each method / field mean. But in general, make your `Card` class implement `Comparable` interface. And define proper `compareTo` method. It would be much simpler afterwards

```
public class Card implements Comparable<Card> {
    private int value;
    private int color;

    //...

    @Override
    public int compareTo(@NotNull Card o) {
        final int valueResult = Integer.compare(value, o.value);
        if (valueResult != 0) {
            return valueResult;
        }
        return Integer.compare(color, o.color);
    }
}
```

And after that you can compare 2 cards by calling `card1.compareTo(card2)`.

Comment: The problem is my task is to do this without using compareTo. I know, I know its dumb but...

Answer (score 0):

> The problem is my task is to do this without using compareTo.

Well, if you need to do it programatically, without using Java sort methods, use a *stable sort* = algorithm that does not rearrange elements that have equal key, e.g. merge sort or insertion sort which is good for gradual inserting.
This case, sort your array first by *color*, then by *value*. Here, a stable sort will left cards with equal *value* in order as sorted by *color*.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Stable_sorts

Example pseudo code:

```
int[][] cards;

cards = mergeSort(cards, cards[1]);
cards = mergeSort(cards, cards[0]);

Object[] mergeSort(Object[] array, int[] keys)  {...}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank You guys for trying but I think what I have to do is to write a method that will determinate where in the LinkedList the newly generated card should be added. Something like this second method "dodaj" I submitted...

Comment: you have to write it to question section (update it with this info). Because it is not an answer to your question. It is only an additional information.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion for you is:

- if you use Java language use naming convention, for your code. It makes your code understandable for others developers.
- use ***Java 8*** for collection operations. It has a lot of features for simplicity collection routines.

I created small demo:

```
@Getter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
class Card {
    private int value;  // 1-13
    private int colour; // 1-3

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return String.valueOf(value + " " + colour);
    }
}

public class ComparatorDemo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final List<Card> cards = Arrays.asList(
                new Card(11, 2),
                new Card(5, 3),
                new Card(2, 3),
                new Card(13, 0),
                new Card(1, 2),
                new Card(5, 2),
                new Card(1, 1),
                new Card(5, 1));

        final Function<Card, Integer> byValue = Card::getValue;
        final Function<Card, Integer> byColour = Card::getColour;

        System.out.println("Before sorting");
        cards.forEach(System.out::println);

        List<Card> sortedList = cards.stream()
                .sorted(Comparator.comparing(byValue).thenComparing(byColour))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());

        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("After sorting");
        sortedList
                .forEach(System.out::println);
    }
}
```

The `Card` class is what you named `Kartka`. I used [Lombok framework](https://www.google.com.ua/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&sqi=2&ved=0ahUKEwie48yOoPfSAhWCCpoKHVvhAEQQFggkMAE&url=https%3A%2F%2Fprojectlombok.org%2F&usg=AFQjCNFMjn-TxyJTJpbCoHBOK6A78_M_gA&sig2=1HCiu5C2ajEQnARFiflEGg&bvm=bv.150729734,d.bGs) annotation `@Getter` for omitting redundant code.
Also, test data has exactly the same values as you mentioned at the question.

***Output is***:

```
Before sorting
11 2
5 3
2 3
13 0
1 2
5 2
1 1
5 1

After sorting
1 1
1 2
2 3
5 1
5 2
5 3
11 2
13 0
```